# Casting an instance of Object to primitive type or Object Type

Tags: java, casting, primitive-types, object-type

when I need to cast an instance of type `Object` to a double , which of the following is better and why ?

`Double d = (Double) object;`

Or

`double d = (double) object;`

Comment: If you _try_ to compile these two options you'll notice something about the second...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference is that the first form will succeed if `object` is null - the second will throw a `NullPointerException`. So if it's valid for `object` to be null, use the first - if that indicates an error condition, use the second.

This:

```
double d = (double) object;
```

is equivalent to:

```
Double tmp = (Double) object;
double t = tmp.doubleValue();
```

(Or just `((Double)object).doubleValue()` but I like separating the two operations for clarity.)

Note that the cast to `double` is only valid under Java 7 - although it's not clear from the [Java 7 language enhancements page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html) why that's true.

Comment: You can do `double d = (double) (Double) object;` in versions of java pre 1.7, this will throw the NPE from the `(double)` cast if `object` is `null`.

Comment: @bmorris591: Indeed - or just call `doubleValue()` directly.

Comment: @bmorris591: I am getting NPE in both jdk 1.6 and 1.7 !

Comment: @mataug: Then presumably `object` is null.

Comment: From @bmorris591 comment I assumed that NPE will be thrown only in pre 1.7, and in 1.7 I would probably get 0 .

Comment: @mataug: No, prior to Java 7 it wouldn't compile.